# amcl_pose topic returns different than the map->odom->base transform

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title states, amcl_pose is not giving me the same result as taking the map->odom transform and then combining that with the odom->base transform. I was originally using the map->odom transform to just correct my drift, but if anything it seems like amcl_pose is right, and the map->odom is wrong, at least based on comparing what I see on Rviz with where my robot actually was.

Rather than just swapping to amcl_pose I want to try and understand what is happening. Let me just show some culled log files from a ROS node that takes in my robots scans/odometry, publishes them for AMCL, and also listens for the amcl_pose topic to be published... All values are (x,y,theta) by the way:

> [ INFO] [1541537079.104442235]: amcl_pose =  0.979757,1.041833,1.677116

> [ INFO] [1541537079.104487697]: map->odom = 0.081080,-0.287248,0.212756

> [ INFO] [1541537080.089657443]: odom->base = 1.164587,1.157537,1.452360

> [ INFO] [1541537081.010870954]: odom->base = 1.170495,1.207187,1.452360

> [ INFO] [1541537082.035011221]: odom->base = 1.176403,1.256837,1.452360

> [ INFO] [1541537083.058245129]: odom->base = 1.181755,1.305040,1.464360

> [ INFO] [1541537084.082075926]: odom->base = 1.186469,1.353310,1.476360

> [ INFO] [1541537085.003592600]: odom->base = 1.190543,1.401638,1.488360

> [ INFO] [1541537086.027702051]: odom->base = 1.193791,1.448525,1.512360

> [ INFO] [1541537087.052686791]: odom->base = 1.196423,1.496953,1.524360

> [ INFO] [1541537088.076706817]: odom->base = 1.198293,1.545416,1.536360

> [ INFO] [1541537088.997988424]: odom->base = 1.199228,1.592406,1.560360

> [ INFO] [1541537089.104671886]: amcl_pose =  0.880494,1.507386,1.807045

> [ INFO] [1541537089.104765416]: map->odom = 0.106420,-0.329653,0.246685

You can clearly see that the last amcl_pose says the robot is at X=0.880494, but removing the drift error AMCL also published from the last published odometry value returns X=1.199-0.106=1.093. The Y value is even farther off!

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding something about AMCL, or misusing it somehow. These *should* be the same right?
Thanks for any help.

---

Update: mgruhler pointed out what I was doing wrong, but I'll explain what I should have done if anyone has the same problem and stumbles upon this:

The odom->base vector is in the odometry frame, a different frame of reference than the map frame. Since there is a rotation between the two, that means you cannot simply sum up their vectors.

Using a rotation matrix with the known rotation (0.246685rad in this case) on the odom->base vector to converts it into the map frame, and then it can simple be summed up with the map->odom vector, and you get the expected answer.

---

Miscellanious info I don't think matters for this issue:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
ROS kinetic 1.12.14

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307758/amcl_pose-topic-returns-different-than-the-map-%3Eodom-%3Ebase-transform/) by [FriendlyFire](https://answers.ros.org/users/38411/friendlyfire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most probably `amcl` is right and you are computing your values incorrectly.

As the transforms you get (i.e. `odom->base` as well as `map->odom`) are not in the same frame, you cannot just add up the single components. The frames (in this case, `odom` with respect to `map`) is rotated. So you have to adjust the `x` and `y` components according to the orientation.
I'll leave it up to you to verify this is correct. Check how to transform coordinate systems.

If you want to get the transform from `map` to `base` in ROS, you can directly ask `tf` to get you this instead of manually adding up the transforms.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FriendlyFire](https://answers.ros.org/users/38411/friendlyfire/) on 2018-11-07**:
Thanks, never thought about that. This also means I can't simply maintain a static error of my odometry on my robot, only updating it occasionally with AMCL. Based on the rotational error AND odometry, I have to constantly update that X/Y error to get my true position. Darn!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-11-08**:
Yes, but why would you want to do that? This would basically lead to your robot having an error in localization that grows and grows until you do an update...